# Cannot play Amazon Prime Video content on Opera

Tags: 20.04, video, browser, opera, amazon

I have a problem with Opera version 70.0.3728.106 on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer. If I try to watch anything on Amazon Prime Video, I get the following message:

> Protected Content Error
> To watch protected content, in the top right of Chrome, click the three dots icon, and then tap Settings > Site settings > Protected content. Under Blocked, tap Amazon.com > Clear and Reset. Refresh or reload the video's detail page, and then tap Watch Now.

The settings of Opera are slightly different than the ones of Chrome, but in any case I have already allowed the Protected Content and I still get the same message. I have other two PCs running Windows 10 and on those PCs I can watch Amazon Prime Video content using Opera without any issue. Moreover, if I use Chrome to watch Amazon Prime Video on my Ubuntu computer I encounter no troubles. Therefore, the problem seems to be in the combination Opera-Ubuntu.

Any idea on what might be the problem?

Comment: the reason for this is prime videos use  DRM protection. Search your opera settings and enable it. It should work fine then

Comment: I cannot find the DRM protection settings on Opera (even by searching them), are you sure the setting does not have another name?

Comment: Well I don't use Opera so I don't know about that but the reason why you can't play videos is because DRM content is not enabled. Did you try the answer provided by man3s?

Answer (score 1):

Opera does not include propietary codecs/libraries in Linux, this worked for me in Debian 10:

**[Update]**

Sorry, I was not explicit, it is not needed dowload all the repository. In the web page (https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt):

1. Go below of the "FFmpeg prebuilt for NW.js" title > "Downloads" subtitle
2. Click in the "here" text in the "Downloads can be found here" option
3. A new webpage will be open (https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases)
4. Click in the 0.47.2-linux-x64.zip  option, the file will be downloaded in your computer (4.69 MB)
5. Descompress the file
6. Go to descompressed files
7. Copy/Move the libffmpeg.so file to the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra/ folder (If the folder
   does not exist, please create it).
8. Restart Opera

Regards.

Comment: It's not solution for DRM video

Comment: This worked for me, cholo14 can test the proposed solution and told us if it works.

Comment: @man3s I downloaded the code you mention but there is no `libffmpeg.so` file inside. Also, the installation guide mentions as requirement 10GB, which sounds too large for just getting one single file

Comment: Hello cholo14, I updated the procedure, you do not need clone the repository, only download the precompiled file. Please check the updated post.

Comment: @man3s thanks for the update. Opera is installed in the path /snap/opera/85/... and if I try to create the directory lib_extra, I get the message: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘lib_extra’: Read-only file system`. The same happens if I try to copy any content inside the folder

Comment: @cholo14 , I am not familiarized with the Snap packages, I installed my Opera using the .deb file available in the official page. Reading in internet, I am not sure if it is possible write in the snap directory. Sorry.

Comment: @man3s I asked another question for solving this other issue. I will let you know if I manage to solve it and implement your answer

Comment: Doing this stopped Opera from opening.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm placing `libffmpeg.so` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra/download
to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra/` make Prime video worked on my Opera which is `Version:79.0.4143.22`